# Screen Scraping With Beautiful Soup to recognize trends in candlestick charts

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, forex

I am attempting to scrape information from a candlestick chart so that I may write it into a CSV file for training my computer to recognize the beginning of a trend with BeautifulSoup(4)
The information that I am looking for is from this website "https://www.dailyfx.com/charts"

I think I got most of my information right, however I need a second pair of eyes on this seeing as how I cannot get the content to print to screen.

Thank you for your help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.dailyfx.com/charts"
r =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
#links = soup.find_all("a")
g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "pane-legend-item-value-container"})

for item in g_data:
    print(item.contents[0].find_all("span",{"class": "pane-legend-item-value-wrap"})[0].text)
    try:
        print(item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"class": "pane-legend-item-value-title pane-legend-live"})[0].text.replace(',',''))
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `g_data` is empty, it never finds anything. The widget on the page is a separate document essentially and it is generated dynamically from tradingview.com. You may need to use something like [Splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).